# Strange Tukey Output

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, post-hoc

I'm using HSD.test in package Agricolae to run a Tukey PostHoc test on heavy metals concentrations in otter livers and kidneys. I'm looking at differences between region, river basin, and age class. Most of the groups are the typical A, B, C, AB, BC, etc... On a few of the outputs (I'm running these tests for 14 different metals) I get group results as "a" and "ab" (see example below). I'm no statistician, but I understand Tukey well enough to know that when there's a "ab" that means that particular mean is not different from group "a" or group "b". My problem is that there's no group "b" listed. I'm stumped on how I should report these results. My advisor has never seen it before. Am I inputting something incorrectly? Is this a sample size issue (there's 317 total specimens for each tissue type (same otters, liver and kidney sample from each).

NORMAL OUTPUT

```
> K_Zn.RIBA.Tukey
$statistics
  MSerror  Df     Mean       CV
  14.1584 306 21.53281 17.47456

$parameters
   test name.t ntr StudentizedRange alpha
  Tukey   RIBA  11         4.586692  0.05

$means
                              K_Zn      std  r  Min  Max
Albemarle-Chowan          20.74359 4.901707 39 14.8 39.9
Cape Fear                 20.65581 3.886564 43 13.4 32.4
French Broad-Holston      22.77812 5.212623 32 16.8 37.3
Lower Pee Dee             21.38108 2.716906 37 16.6 30.8
Middle Tennessee-Hiwassee 35.50000       NA  1 35.5 35.5
Neuse                     21.47381 2.989499 42 14.0 29.2
Onslow Bay                29.90000 2.687006  2 28.0 31.8
Pamlico                   21.37500 2.401789 40 17.4 26.9
Roanoke                   21.60556 3.717284 18 14.9 29.6
Santee                    22.13333 3.583133 24 16.7 31.6
Upper Pee Dee             21.44615 3.798050 39 16.5 33.9
                             Q25   Q50    Q75
Albemarle-Chowan          17.850 20.00 22.250
Cape Fear                 18.200 19.80 22.300
French Broad-Holston      19.200 20.90 26.200
Lower Pee Dee             20.100 21.00 22.500
Middle Tennessee-Hiwassee 35.500 35.50 35.500
Neuse                     19.550 20.65 23.425
Onslow Bay                28.950 29.90 30.850
Pamlico                   19.725 20.85 22.775
Roanoke                   18.725 20.45 23.625
Santee                    19.675 21.50 24.325
Upper Pee Dee             18.550 20.80 22.550

$comparison
NULL

$groups
                              K_Zn groups
Middle Tennessee-Hiwassee 35.50000      a
Onslow Bay                29.90000     ab
French Broad-Holston      22.77812     bc
Santee                    22.13333     bc
Roanoke                   21.60556     bc
Neuse                     21.47381     bc
Upper Pee Dee             21.44615     bc
Lower Pee Dee             21.38108     bc
Pamlico                   21.37500     bc
Albemarle-Chowan          20.74359      c
Cape Fear                 20.65581      c
```

STRANGE OUTPUT

```
> L_Mo.age.Tukey
$statistics
     MSerror  Df      Mean       CV
  0.04016151 312 0.7958517 25.18099

$parameters
   test name.t ntr StudentizedRange alpha
  Tukey  AGECL   5         3.880316  0.05

$means
       L_Mo       std   r   Min  Max     Q25    Q50     Q75
0 0.7493538 0.1499703  65 0.480 1.16 0.65100 0.7420 0.85000
1 0.7684381 0.1694864 105 0.407 1.25 0.62800 0.7410 0.89500
2 0.8107170 0.1922619  53 0.464 1.35 0.69100 0.7690 0.91800
3 0.8525000 0.2706481  32 0.547 1.67 0.65650 0.7845 0.96275
4 0.8490806 0.2531951  62 0.447 1.91 0.71225 0.7945 0.93250

$comparison
NULL

$groups
       L_Mo groups
3 0.8525000      a
4 0.8490806      a
2 0.8107170     ab
1 0.7684381     ab
0 0.7493538     ab

attr(,"class")
[1] "group"
```

CODE

```
library (agricolae)
library(readr)
WORK_Filter_LOD <- read_csv("C:/Otter/Otter Project/Data/WORK_Filter_LOD.csv")
View(WORK_Filter_LOD)
Otter<-WORK_Filter_LOD
Otter$AGECL<-factor(Otter$AGECL)
L_Mo.AGE.lm<-lm(L_Mo~AGECL, data=Otter)
L_Mo.AGE.av<-aov(L_Mo.AGE.lm)
L_Mo.age.Tukey<-HSD.test(L_Mo.AGE.av, "AGECL", group = TRUE)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Presumably the last three means listed form group b and all five form group a but I do not use this software so it is just an assumption.

Comment: That was my thought, but if all of them are "a" wouldn't that mean that none of them are different?